# Hide a widget inside a div on specific type of post

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, widgets, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a custom post type called "product" and I want to hide an specific widget only if the post type is "product" I was trying with something like this:

```
<?php function hidewidget() {
   $args = array(
   'name' => 'product'
   );
   $output = 'objects';
   $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output );
   return $post_types; } 
   $widhide = hidewidget(); 
?>

   <?php 
      if ($widhide = 'product') {
      } else { 
   ?>
    <div class="widgetclass"><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'filters' ); ?></div>
   <?php } ?>
```

The problem is the following: this function just return the name, I can't do anything with the name.

I need to call a function wich return a page with an specific kind of post.

It's possible in wordpress? any other solution to hide that div on the product detail page in woocommerce?

pd: **I can't remove `.widgetclass`** **it needs to be there**, I try with a plugin "widget display" to hide the widget but the `.widgetclass` div was still appearing obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check if it's the specific post_type..

```
if (is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
   //do nothing if it's a singular product page
}else{
  <div class="widgetclass"><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'filters' ); ?></div>
{
```

Make sure that the actual post type is just "product" and isn't namespaced.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Widget Logic plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) and use the conditional inside the field:

```
! is_singular( 'product' )
```

This will show up on all but single product pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional after the function name in the code which calls your widget.

```
if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) 
    return:
```

Or

```
if ( ! is_singular( 'product' ) )
```

Uses the ! NOT [`Logical operator`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) with the [`is_singular`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) conditional tag